# Is there a REST API to create a new Data Connection in InfoSphere?

Tags: rest, ibm-information-server

I would like to programatically add a Data Connection to IBM Information Server using a REST API (just as I would by clicking 'Create Connection' in the UI) so that I can create associated Assets (e.g. Database, Schema, Table, Column)

I've reviewed the currently available APIs by going to [server]/ibm/iis/igc-rest-explorer/. I believe I would need a `POST` to `/assets/`, but the implementation notes state:

> Create an asset by passing in a JSON object with the required and additional properties (currently supported: term, category, information_governance_policy, information_governance_rule, collection, label, data_class). Must include a '_type' field as well as all required fields.

This does not include the ability to add assets of id `data_connection` or any of the `database_*` ones. Is there a different approach (not sure if Open IGC is applicable or helpful) to be able to programatically add (create/`POST`) the aforementioned asset types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Infosphere Information Metadata Asset Manager to create new data connections (via GUI or CLI).

Further details are available at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.mmi.doc/topics/r_imam_cmd_createdc.html